# I'm getting the error TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, typeerror, replit

I am new to python, but I am getting this error and don't know how to solve it.

```
numbers = [100, 50, 10, 1, 2, 7, 11, 17, 53, -8, -4, -9, -72, -64, -80]
b=1
while b>=1:
  if (numbers % 2) == 1:
    print(numbers[b])
    b += 2
  else:
    break
```

Comment: `numbers % 2` is the problem. `numbers` is a list and the code does not make sense (`numbers % 2`)

Comment: What do you expect `numbers % 2` to do?

Comment: i was attempting mod it by 2 to find if the number from the list is odd

Comment: Maybe you forgot to put `numbers[b] % 2` ? Do you need to stop at the first even number ?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to find the odd numbers:

```
numbers = [100, 50, 10, 1, 2, 7, 11, 17, 53, -8, -4, -9, -72, -64, -80]
for number in numbers:
  if number % 2:
     print(f"Found odd: {number}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`numbers` is a list and you can't use modulo with a list only with an integer.

`if (numbers % 2) == 1:`

should probably look like:

`if (numbers[b] % 2) == 1:`

Sidenote: In most programming languages arrays / lists start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can slightly modify your own code. Remember since number is a list you can run `numbers%2`, because you cannot run modulo on a list, only on an integer. Using a for loop in this case makes sure that entire list is iterated over to give you the odd numbers you are looking for

```
numbers = [100, 50, 10, 1, 2, 7, 11, 17, 53, -8, -4, -9, -72, -64, -80]
b=1
while b>=1:
  for i in numbers:
      if i%2 == 1:
         print(numbers[b])
         b += 2
      else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting happens because of this line:

```py
if (numbers % 2) == 1:
```

You should see [what farbiondriven said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66317486/12253585), but also note that you're saying to Python "divide this list by 2", and Python doesn't know what to do, so it throws an Error

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to print out only the **odd numbers** from the given list 'numbers', you can try the following code.

```
numbers = [100, 50, 10, 1, 2, 7, 11, 17, 53, -8, -4, -9, -72, -64, -80]
for b in range(len(numbers)):
if numbers[b] % 2 == 1:
    print(numbers[b])
```